# chrome v8 standard input function?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm writing an online exam and when I submit the file with **readline()** to the website it says runtime error.The site is using D8 3.14 compiler.So what should I use to provide standard input in v8??

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking about Google Chrome or are you asking about V8 (not Chrome) running in the terminal?

Comment: What is the runtime error specifically? And what would you expect to be supplied on stdin? Apart from that, [`readline` seems to be fine](http://www.sandeepdatta.com/2011/10/using-v8-javascript-shell-d8.html).